# Why can't we pass strings as template arguments?

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I know we can define templates using constants. For instance:

```
template<int N>
struct FixedArray {
   double values[N];
   int size() { return N; }   // Could be static
};


int main(int, char**)  {
   FixedArray<10> arr;
   arr.values[0] = 3.14;
   cout << "first element=" << arr.values[0] << endl;
   cout << "size=" << arr.size() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

This specific example lets us define an array with a constant size.

But why can't we pass strings as template arguments in C++?

The following slide is suppose to explain it but I'm not getting where the problem is.

If someone can point it out to me and explain it I'd appreciate it.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Which part of the slide didn’t you get?

Comment: I've edited my question. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, "because the standard says so". Since template arguments serve to form a *type*, they must be sufficiently unambiguous. The following works, though:

```
template <char *> struct Foo { };

char x;

int main()
{
    Foo<&x> a;
}
```

The point is that `x` is now a well-defined, named object with linkage, so its address is a globally, sta­ti­cally known quantity. The pointer derived from a string literal does not have the same qualities; it is not the address of a named variable.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I see the difference between an interger pointer and a char pointer. 
Why does it matter if it's the address a named variable or not?

Comment: @Shookie: There is no difference between the two pointer types. Let me edit it to make it less confusing.

Comment: @Shookie: The address of a named variable is the only kind of pointer value that is allowed as a non-type template argument. It's the only kind of non-linteral constant that is "sufficiently constant".